# Unicodes for Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons

Tags: css, unicode, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to find these anywhere. I just need the little number/letter combo (Unicode) for bootstrap 3's glyphicons so I can add one in via CSS. I know you can do it HTML, but I do not have that option in this particular instance. Below is an example of FontAwesome's Unicode for CSS for reference.

```
.element:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Comment: http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually find these on the first website you get when you search for "bootstrap glyphicon unicode" on Google.

http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/

Click on "Copy", underneath the glyphicon you want.
And click on "CSS Rule" in the dropdown-menu.

It will copy the CSS rule to your clipboard.

Simply paste that into your CSS file. Done.

Comment: Thanks. Adding to favorites now. I have no idea why bootstrap would have that info posted to their site, nor did it appear on a Google search.

Comment: Glad I could help you.